# I want to create lists in order to split to puzzle an image(Python image processing)

Tags: python, image, list

i have an image (size: X x Y)

i want to split image.

original image :

[image: Sample Image]

spliting and changing lists:

[image: Sample Image]

if i split 2*2, lists will be following

num is split number 2,3 or more

```
list1 = img[0:round(x/num), 0:round(y/num)]   
list2 = img[0:round(x/num), round(y/num):y]  
list3 = img[round(x/num):x, 0:round(y/num)]  
list4 = img[round(x/num):x, round(y/num):y]
```

if i split 3*3, lists will be

```
list1 = img[0:round(x/num),              0:round(y/num)]
list2 = img[round(x/num):round(2*x/num), 0:round(y/num]
list3 = img[round(2*x/num):x,            0:round(y/num)]
list4 = img[0:round(x/num),              round(y/num):round(2*y/num)]
list5 = img[round(x/num):round(2*x/num), round(y/num):round(2*y/num)]
list6 = img[round(2*x/num):x,            round(y/num):round(2*y/num)]
list7 = img[0:round(x/num),              round(2*y/3):y]
list8 = img[round(x/num):round(2*x/num), round(2*y/3):y]
list9 = img[round(2*x/num):x,            round(2*y/3):y]
```

for 4*4 lists will be 16

how can i write code in loop for this question?

Comment: Please review your question for typos. I suspect e.g. "list1" != "liste1"; "numn" != "num". These are obstacles for clarity. Then explain all your identifiers. Do not make readers guess at the meaning of "num".

Comment: Sorry. Its my first time. I am writing again

Comment: Consider not using several lists named starting with 1. Instead use an array, starting at index 0. Then try to spot the relationship between the index of each entry and the digits in your expected result. Three of your "2"s are for example "index/num".

Comment: i tried it. But example : " allList[0]=list1 ; allList[1]=list2 " is not valid. (error)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of that code and its undesried output. Or explain what otherwise you mean by "is not valid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image can be represented as a list of 2D arrays for each elementary colors (Red, Green, Blue). For instance, you can load an image using `scipy.misc.imread`:

```
from scipy.misc import imread

img_rgb = imread("sample.jpg")
```

For each color array, you can successively use `np.array_split` (NumPy function) to split your array along a given dimension, following

```
def split_img(img, num):
    # Here, img is a 2D array
    img_split = [ np.array_split(A, num, axis = 0) for A in np.array_split(img, num, axis = 1) ]
    # Flatten the output into a list of 2D arrays
    return [ item for sublist in img_split for item in sublist ]

num = 4
img_r_split = split_img(img_rgb[:,:,0], num)
img_g_split = split_img(img_rgb[:,:,1], num)
img_b_split = split_img(img_rgb[:,:,2], num)
```

Finally, you must gather the split color arrays into an RGB array, following

```
img_rgb_split = [ np.stack((r, g, b), axis = -1) for r, g, b in zip(img_r_split, img_g_split, img_b_split) ]
```

You can use `plt.imshow` to display your split images, for instance

```
plt.imshow(img_rgb_split[0])
```

Comment: ıt works definitely. But i have to solve with pixels(elements of lists)

Comment: I edited my answer to treat an image (which is simply a list of three 2D arrays).

Comment: Yes it works. But how can i concatenate the images on one image

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to write the different images in a file?

Comment: img_rgb_split[0] ,  img_rgb_split[1], img_rgb_split[2] , img_rgb_split[3]  i can show these on different windows. i want to concatenate them

Comment: Could you explain this ? what is A? img_split = [ np.array_split(A, num, axis = 0) for A in np.array_split(img, num, axis = 1) ]